# In android my pojo class instance are getting null value

Tags: java, android, json, instance, pojo

i have created a pojo class.. where i store data which i am getting from api..

In MainActivity.java i am using loopj for parsing json data

```
storeList = new ArrayList<AllStore>();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(responseBody));
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        store = new AllStore();

                        store.setLocation(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("storeName"));
                        store.setAddress(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("address"));
```

my pojo class

AllStore.java

```
public class AllStore{

String storeName;
String address;

public AllStore(String storeName, String address){
this.storeName= storeName;
this.location = location;
}

public AllStore{

}

public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

public String getStoreName() {
        return storeName;
    }

    public void setStoreName(String storeName) {
        this.storeName = storeName;
    }

}
```

In other java classes.. rather then adapter class when i am doing

```
AllStore allStore = new Allstore();

mText.setText(allStore.getStoreName);
```

Here allStore.getStoreName value is null showing.. how to solve this..

Please help

Comment: Use debugger, by the way this.location = location; while there is no param named location in the constructor

Comment: There are multiple issues with the code that you provided here. It shouldn't even compile.

Comment: why @lupz ?? its compiling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AllStore allStore = new Allstore();

mText.setText(allStore.getStoreName());
```

Here you are creating a new object Allstore with the default constructor

```
public AllStore{

}
```

If you call `.getStoreName` it will return null because you haven´t set any.

In the other method, you have to add the store object in te array list

```
store.setLocation(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("storeName"));        
store.setAddress(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("address"));
storeList.add(store);
```

Later if you want to use the name of the item in the list you can do:

```
mText.setText(storelist.get(index).getStoreName());
```

Where `index` is the position in the list of the item.

Comment: yes i have added storeList.add(store); in mainActivity.. i am using this text in a very diffrent class.. so how i will get there storelist.get(position) postion i cant get r8 ??

Comment: you have to get the object where you want to use, in this case, storelist must be sended to the class. You can create an Async task to get the items from json and put in storelist and then, return it where you need it.